Is electron affinity of noble gases zero or positive?
I am finding this incredibly confusing. We define electron affinity as the energy released when one mole of electrons is added to one mole of gaseous atoms to form one mole of gaseous ions with a single negative charge. In general, adding an electron is exothermic because the electron is attracted to the positively charged nucleus. Now for elements such as Neon, an electron experiences no attraction to the positively charged nucleus because the effective nuclear charge is zero. I think this is why people state that the electron affinity of an element such as Neon is zero. However, I don't understand why this is. If we wanted to attach an electron to Neon, we could, but it would require energy to do this. So shouldn't the electron affinity be some positive value, rather than zero?

I think you mean negative and yes they are https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_affinity_(data_page)

There are no stable noble gas anions. The helium -1 anion has a lifetime in microseconds, the rest much shorter.

Following @JonCuster one can argue that the correct answer to the question is simply "No". As there are no stable, in the sense of a minimum on the potential energy surface, noble gas anions their electron affinity is not positive or zero or negative, it just doesn't exist.

The electron affinity of an atom or molecule is defined as the amount of energy released when an electron attaches to a neutral atom or molecule in the gaseous state to form an anion.
Considering that noble gas ionisation is endothermic (requires energy to get ionised, as you stated in your question) the electron affinity would be negative.
Consideration of electron electron repulsions and electronic configuration of an atom is often more important than ‘nucleus attracts electron’

Neutral atom ionisation is always endothermic. M -> M+ + e- is not the opposite process to M + e- -> M-.
